# The first is convex, and the second is linear when x>2. is it ambiguity?

Tags: sentence, ambiguity

In my paper, I want to say, the first is convex all the time, and the second is linear when x>2.

I am afraid that some people will think that: The first is convex when x>2, and the second is linear when x>2.  How to avoid it?

The space in my thesis is very precious, so I combined the two simple sentences into one.

There are two functions F(x) and G(x). So I summarized the characters of them into a Lemma: **Both the F(x) and G(x) are decreasing functions. The first is convex, and the second is linear when x>2**.

Comment: Please provide the broader context (eg surrounding paragraphs), or we can't offer any useful guidance. We need to know what these "first" and "second" things *are*.

Comment: Because you're primarily contrasting *convex/linear*, it's confusing to say the second one is ***only*** linear in certain contexts (I assume from your perspective it *is* linear in the vast majority of contexts). So I would rephrase to *the first one is convex all the time, and the second one is linear **except when x<=2***.

Comment: There are two functions F(x) and G(x). So I summarized the characters of the two functions into a Lemma: Both the F(x) and G(x) are decreasing functions. The first is convex, and the second one is linear when x>2.

Comment: Personally I do not there is any need to worry, but if you do, why not say: The first one is convex. The second one is linear when (=if) x>2.

Comment: You already said that in the question itself. Are you interested in negative values of x? If not, obviously there are far more possible values that are > 2, so it makes sense to reduce the importance of the "less likely" situation using ***only***. If there's no reason to consider either as more important / common that the other then I think it's a mistake to try to join your two statements into a single sentence, since *they would have no useful connection*.

Comment: "The first one is convex for all x, and the second..."

Answer (score 2):

Why not say

> The first one is convex all the time, and the second one is linear only when *x*>2.

Your own suggestion is unambiguous. You could adjust it slightly:

> The first one is convex for all *x,* and the second one is linear only when *x*>2.

Comment: +1, but the "one's" make it a little awkward.  "The first is convex ..., and the second in linear ...." is better.

Comment: One answer is :The first is convex, and when x>2 the second is linear. How about that?

Comment: I want to write a concise language

Comment: My point was that what you had in your question when you described what you want to say is quite unambiguous. You could omit the "ones", as cobaltduck suggests.

Comment: I think "all the time" is awkward where a function (i.e., function domain) is concerned.

Comment: @anemone Quite. My point was that the OP's own explanation was unambiguous, and using "for all *x*" would be a better expression.

Comment: Yes, the "one" has been removed now.

Comment: @ Andrew Leach Thanks. The final version is now **Both the F(x) and G(x) are decreasing functions. The first is convex for \forall x, and the second is linear when x>2.**

Answer (score 0):

Since the comma is placed after *convex*, I read the x>2 constraint as applying only to the *second one*. However, I agree that the sentence has the potential for ambiguity. To remove the potential ambiguity, just rearrange the wording slightly:

> The first is convex, and when x>2 the second one is linear.